# 405 (Method Not Allowed): angular4

Tags: angular, rest, angular-cli, angular4-forms

I try post data to backend with angular 4 (I try apply authentification with angular4) but I have this error:

[image]

I use extension google chrome for resolve error cros but also error
code service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Data } from '../Data';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {  RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
export class DataServiceService {


  constructor(private http:HttpClient,public router:Router) { }

  Login(data)
  {

    let headers: any = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post('link api',JSON.stringify(data),{responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res),err => {console.log(err); if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(`/login`);
        }});

  }


    public getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

    public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    let token = this.getToken();
    if (token === null) return false; else return true;
  }
}
```

code component:

```
      mySubmit({value,valid}:{value:Data,valid:boolean})
  {
    if (valid === true) { console.log(value);
        this.dataService.Login(value);

     } else console.log('error');
  }
```

code interceptors:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import { DataServiceService } from './data-service.service';
  import {Router} from '@angular/router';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

  @Injectable()
  export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  //inj:Injector;

    constructor(public inj: Injector,public router:Router) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

     const auth = this.inj.get(DataServiceService);
     const authToken = auth.getToken();
     const clonedRequest = req.clone({
              headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`)
              .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          });


      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
```

now when send data I have error 405 Method Not Allowed and in interceptors i add application/json to Content-Type but also error

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding those request headers will cause the browser to send an OPTION request before it sends your POST request. You need to change your backend server config to allow the OPTIONS request by enabling CORS.

You haven't mentioned what backend you are using, but if it is .net core for example you could follow the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors